# Is the Matter energy-momentum tensor zero identically for the following specific case?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, maxwell-equations, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

With source term Einstein-Maxwell LAgrangian

$$L = R  - F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu\nu} - 2A_\mu J^\mu + L_\mathrm{matter}$$

gives
$$
G_{\mu\nu} = \kappa^2 ( T^\mathrm{Maxwell}_{\mu\nu}  +   T^\mathrm{Matter}_{\mu\nu} )
$$

Since $\nabla^\mu G_{\mu \nu} = 0 $ identically,
 the right hand side

$$\nabla^\mu (T^\mathrm{Maxwell}_{\mu\nu}  +   T^\mathrm{Matter}_{\mu\nu})= 0 .$$

**My question is this:**   Then can we say

$$\nabla^\mu T^\mathrm{Matter}_{\mu\nu} = 0~? $$

Comment: Suppose that is true, what does it say about Eq 3?

Comment: Do you have any charged matter?